# Android Search Widget in Actionbar and second unnecessary search on top

Tags: android, search, android-widget, searchview

I want to create a search for the user in the ActionBar. I use the SearchView Widget as an Action View. But when I include the 
            
part in the manifest, it also pops up a second search on top. Both the view on top and the ActionBar Search work. When I remove the part from the manifest, the second Search doesn't pop up and only the one in the ActionBar does, but nothing happens when I hit the search button.

This is how it looks:

[image: both ways]

I only want the second view not the white search on top. Perhaps somebody easily sees whats wrong.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/BlueTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".helper.SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".helper.SearchResultsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>


    </application>
```

The part of the Fragment(as part of MainActivity) which handles the search:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.persons, menu);
    Log.d("ml Person", "creating Options Menu for Persons");
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            getActivity().onSearchRequested();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

widget in menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint_persons" />
```